# How can I update a document list field without overriding it in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I have the following document:

```
{
  "_id":ObjectId("idhere"),
  "locations":[
    {
       "latitude":3453.4353,
       "longitude":31.123
    },
    {
       "latitude":1243.134,
       "longitude":992.321
    }
  ]
}
```

The question is:

How can I update this document locations' without overriding the entire list,just by appending a new location to the existing ones? I know that to update a document I have to use this query:

`db.collection.update({ _id : ....}, {$set : { locations : ... }})` but here is the problem -> in this way I should get the existing locations before, add the new location to this array and execute the query with the updated array which would take a lot of time & resources if the `locations` array grows.

Any suggestions? (P.S.: I'm currently using the MongoDB in a spring-boot project and I'm using `MongoRepository` interface to communicate with the DB.)

Comment: Yes, it answers my question, but I've already posted an answer to my question which is the same as what you've mentioned. Thank you very much anyway, I didn't found that when I was searching on google.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution for this question in the mongodb docs [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) at the "Examples" section.

A more detailed picture here:
[image]

The saving solution is to use `$push` instead of `$set`.